# Google recaptcha V2 supported content types

Tags: post, mime-types, content-type, recaptcha

When querying the state of the "I'm not a robot" user challenge, you have to make a POST request to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` passing your secret key and the response token to know the result of the challenge. But it is undocumented which `Content-Type`s (MIME types) are supported. I guess every common MIME type is supported (application/x-www-form-urlenconded, application/json, application/xml), but, just for curiosity,

- Which are the `Content-Type`s supported by `siteverify`?
- Or is that "supported mime types" list for POST request standarized somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I could not make `application/json` with a JSON encoded request function, but I was able to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and verify it still works [as it used to](https://github.com/zemirco/simple-recaptcha/blob/master/index.js) after substituting newer parameter names and https for http.