# Client error: bad request. Error 400. NoCaptcha Laravel Anhskohbo

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I connect the re-captcha to the site, which is built on Laravel. And when you click on "I am not a robot", and then on "registration", this error appears.

In the past, I connected the re-captcha on the framework yii2. I had no such problems with exceptions. Now I Installed captcha - Anhskohbo NoCaptcha.

The error itself looks like a notification:

```
Client error: POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "bad-request"
  ]
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), this error is given when the request is malformed. Can you check what values are being passed to the /siteverify endpoint? The first thing that comes to mind is that the `Content-Type:` header for the request to Google's endpoint should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as per [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707075/google-recaptcha-v2-supported-content-types) - this is also true in my experience.